# Why is PostgreSQL TimeStamp default value not inserting date?

Tags: postgresql

I have column defined like:

```
ALTER TABLE "SalesOrderHeader" ALTER COLUMN "CreatedDate"  SET DEFAULT now();
```

and the value I get inserted looks like

> 0001-01-01 00:09:24-05:50:36

Why isn't the date being inserted?

Sorry I forgot to include the type:

```
"CreatedDate" timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
```

Comment: What's the type of `CreatedDate` and what does `SELECT now();` return?

Comment: `SELECT now();` gives "2017-05-11 10:41:46.913833-05"

Comment: I have gone back and forth with timezone and without and trying differrent default values like `localtimestamp` , `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `now()` none of them are giving me the date.

Comment: In what client do you see that value? (Maybe the values in the table are actually good, but your client has a hard time to understand them). At least the `-05:50:36` as a time-zone offset looks **really** strange to me.

Comment: Show us your insert statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The insert is done with an O/RM tool and I don't even include CreatedDate in the model.

Comment: @pozs I am using PGAdmin to view the data on windows. The database itself is on debian linux.